# Error : Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, function, sql-server-2005

My Function is as Following ::

---

```
Create Function dbo.fnFcid(@url varchar)
 Returns int

 As

 BEGIN
 Return ( select ID from  TTI_fat.dbo.FormContext
          where caseId = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@url, PATINDEX('%&c=%', @url)+ 3, (PATINDEX('%&y=%', @url) - (PATINDEX('%&c=%', @url)+3)))) 
          and   YearID = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@url, PATINDEX('%&y=%', @url)+ 3, (PATINDEX('%&e=%', @url) - (PATINDEX('%&y=%', @url)+3)))) 
          and   EntityID = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@url, PATINDEX('%&e=%', @url)+ 3, (PATINDEX('%&g=%', @url) - (PATINDEX('%&e=%', @url)+3))))
          and   GroupID = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@url, PATINDEX('%&g=%', @url)+ 3, (PATINDEX('%&v=%', @url) - (PATINDEX('%&g=%', @url)+3)))) 
         )  
   END;
 Go
```

---

when I am passing a following value to function

---

```
select dbo.fnFcid('http://localh0st/web/forms/getForm.asp?page=FKYASDENPLFPg1V2014&c=9&y=283&e=1022&g=2&v=1&x=296807&j=161037&z=1')
```

---

its shows me following error

---

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem Fixed of my aboves question 
Its due to  i forgot to mention varchar size while declaring function

```
Create Function dbo.fnFcid(@url varchar(max))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Substring expression is the cause behind error.

Substring syntax is **SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )**.

Your **length** part of code is:

```
(PATINDEX('%&y=%', @url) - (PATINDEX('%&c=%', @url)+3))
```

if your **@url** does not contain `&y=` and `&c=` then length will become **-3**.

Hence because of negative length tsql generates error.

Handle negative part and it will run without error.

Comment: Hello Pratik, &y and &c will be always in url Bcoz they are Important parameter of url. well my question is that even though @url contain that parameter and  no issue of passing the negative value. why this fuunction does not work ?

Comment: for testing, hardcode length value of all substring expressions to something positive. Run the function and let me know if issue exists. I think somewhere your substring is getting negative length.

Comment: Thank you Pratik. Well Problem Fixed. You can refer my answer.

Comment: oh...I missed that part. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss the length in varchar, If you don't mention the length it will take as 1.

```
Create Function dbo.fnFcid(@url varchar(255))
 Returns int

 As

 BEGIN
 Return ( select ID from  TTI_fat.dbo.FormContext
          where caseId = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@url, PATINDEX('%&c=%', @url)+ 3, (PATINDEX('%&y=%', @url) - (PATINDEX('%&c=%', @url)+3)))) 
          and   YearID = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@url, PATINDEX('%&y=%', @url)+ 3, (PATINDEX('%&e=%', @url) - (PATINDEX('%&y=%', @url)+3)))) 
          and   EntityID = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@url, PATINDEX('%&e=%', @url)+ 3, (PATINDEX('%&g=%', @url) - (PATINDEX('%&e=%', @url)+3))))
          and   GroupID = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@url, PATINDEX('%&g=%', @url)+ 3, (PATINDEX('%&v=%', @url) - (PATINDEX('%&g=%', @url)+3)))) 
         )  
   END;
 Go
```